# How to use regex as field separator in awk?

Tags: regular-expression, awk

I'm trying to use regex as a field seperator in `awk`. From my reading this seems possible but I can't get the syntax right.

```
rpm -qa | awk '{ 'FS == [0-9]' ; print $1 }'
awk: cmd. line:1: { FS
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Thoughts? The goal if not obviouse is to get a list of software without version number.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have mucked up your quotes and syntax.   To set the input field separator, the easiest way to do it is with the `-F` option on the command line:

```
awk -F '[0-9]' '{ print $1 }'
```

or

```
awk -F '[[:digit:]]' '{ print $1 }'
```

This would use any digit as the input field separator, and then output the first field from each line.

The `[0-9]` and `[[:digit:]]` expressions are not *quite* the same, depending on your locale.  See "[Difference between [0-9], [[:digit:]] and \d](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414226)".

One could also set `FS` in the `awk` program itself.  This is usually done in a `BEGIN` block as it's a one-time initialisation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[0-9]" } { print $1 }'
```

Note that single quotes can't be used in a single-quoted string in the shell, and that `awk` strings *always* use double quotes.

Comment: Is it possible to access the FS and see the string it matched?

Comment: @Roland `grep -o -E '[0-9]' file` would show you all the instances that matches the separator `[0-9]`, using `grep` to extract them.  I'm using `-E` here to enable extended regular expressions in `grep` as that is what `awk` uses by default (the regular expression `[0-9]` does not actually need `-E` to be enabled).

Answer (score 15):

+1 for Kusalananda's answer. Alternately, the FS variable can be set in the BEGIN block:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[0-9]"} {print $1}'
```

Changing FS in a action block won't take effect until the next line is read

```
$ printf "%s\n" "abc123 def456" "ghi789 jkl0" | awk '{FS="[0-9]"; print $1}'
abc123
ghi
```

The other errors in the question:

- can't use single quotes inside a single-quoted string
- `==` is a comparison operator, `=` is for variable assignment

Comment: "Changing FS in a action block won't take effect until the next line is read" I've been looking all over for that info.

Comment: plus: can't use single quotes for string value in awk, even if you pass them from shell correctly

Comment: Is it possible to access the FS and see the string it matched?

Comment: `FS` is a variable so you do anything like any other variable (e.g `print FS`). To get the parts that match FS, with POSIX awk, I think you cannot. With GNU awk you could write `n = split($0, fields, FS, separators)` where `fields` and `separators` are arrays.