# Awk : extract the actual value of a RegExp pattern match

Tags: awk, gawk

In the following awk code part, `file` contains a file name with its full Linux path that may include a directory of the type `backup-YYMMDD` where YYMMDD is a date.

I would like to assign YYMMDD to `isDate[file]`, that is `isDate[file]=YYMMDD`.

How can I do that?

```c
for (file in files) {
        if ( file ~ /(^|\/)(library|labs data|current)(\/|$)/ ) {
           isKeep[file]
        }
        else if ( file ~ /(^|\/)(backup-[0-2][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])(\/|$)/ ) {
            isDate[file]
        }
        else {
            isDelete[file]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `awk` has the `match` command which allows you to extract the actual value of string components characterized by a pattern. Thus, you could use

```
match(file,"^[[:print:]]*(backup-[0-2][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])[[:print:]]*$",pats);
isDate[file]=pats[1]
```

in the `else if ....` part of your program. The (array) variable `pats` will then be filled with all `(...)`-enclosed sub-expressions in your RegExp which are found in the string, starting with **index 1** (`pats[0]` would be the actual value of the *entire* expression). Since we only have one sub-expression thus grouped (the `backup-YYMMDD` part), `pats[1]` contains what you are looking for.

Alternatively, you could try directly

```
...
   else if (match(file,"^[[:print:]]*(backup-[0-2][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])[[:print:]]*$",pats)==1) {
      isDate[file]=pats[1]
   }
...
```

Note that this approach, of course, relies on the being **only one** path component containing the `backup-YYMMDD` pattern.

**Edit** (on a note by the OP, @macxpat)

I used string constants (`"^[[:print:]] ... $"`) for specifying the regular expression in this answer. However, as noted in the [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps), **it is cleaner and more efficient to specify them as regular expression constants**. Thus, better use

```
match(file,/^[[:print:]]*(backup-[0-2][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])[[:print:]]*$/,pats)
```

in the above examples!

Comment: Thank you! This exactly answers my question. I appreciate also your clear description: "a command which allows you to extract the actual value of string components characterized by a pattern". I have modified the title of my question in accordance, so it may be more useful to others. I was not able to make a successful search because I couldn't even formulate in plain words what I wanted to do!

Comment: I have slightly modified your code to this `... else if (match(file, /(^|\/)backup-([0-2][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])(\/|$)/, pats)>0) { isDate[file]=pats[2] } ...`. I have two questions: 1) what is the meaning of `[[:print:]]` in your code? (couldn't find an answer) ; 2) Is there a particular reason for your use of a string constant ("…")  instead of  regexp constant (/…/)?

Comment: You're welcome! Concerning question (1): As you probably know, `[ ... ]` defines a "character list", i.e. a list of characters accepted at this position of the RegExp. The `[:print:]` is a "character class" and interpreted as "any printable character" (as opposed to control characters). Thus, `[[:print:]]` is a character list containing (only) all printable characters. There are similar constructs for digits, alphanumeric etc., but note that these are all POSIX extensions. As for question (2): it's actually a bad habit probably  taken over from C `printf`; using RegExp constants is cleaner.

Comment: As for character classes, the `[[:digit:]]` is particularly useful as replacement for `[0-9]` because the interpretation of _that_ kind of specification depends on the locale-specific character sort order and may not always mean `0123456789`!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possible differences between `[0-9]` and `[[:digit:]]` for some locales (found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414226/difference-between-0-9-digit-and-d#414230) interesting too), and for the detailed explanation on `[[:print:]]` (finally found info on it and its friends on Wikipedia's [RegExp page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes)). It's indeed more secure to parse the path with it. BTW, paths in this database contain only one directory of the type `backup-YYMMDD`, so the match is safe.

Comment: The function `match` normally returns the position of the pattern in the string matched by the regular expression. But I've noticed that if the RegExp contains `^[[:print:]]*` in front of the pattern (like in your code), `match` always returns `1`. Do you know why?  Is it the reason why you used it?

Comment: The reason for the behaviour is that I anchored the RegExp at the beginning of the line using the `^` symbol, so if the regular expression matches at all, it must by definition match at position 1 in the string. Notice that `match` returns the position where the _entire_ RegExp occurs, not only the `( ... )`-grouped sub-expression. In the check whether a line matches at all, I could as well have said `if (match( ... )!=0)` to exclude non-matching lines; forcing it to be equal `1` can serve as a (not really necessary) consistency check ...

Comment: Btw, please notice that "the comment section is not for extended discussions". If you have further need for clarification, opening up a [chat] may be the better means (although I personally think your questions are of interest to a wider audience).