# Proposed additional POSIX "Character Classes"

Tags: posix, locale, unicode

There are a handful of "character classes" defined in POSIX as in [LC_CTYPE locale definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01) with the following (12) names:

```
alnum alpha blank cntrl digit graph lower print punct space upper xdigit
```

And used as `[[:lower:][:digit:]]`.

Each was set to define a very exact list of characters.
For example, `digit` was meant to include only the characters `0123456789`.

However, with time and use, [the exact definition of a `digit` has been changing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414226/difference-between-0-9-digit-and-d). Perl clearly match more than `0123456789`. Grep may also match more than `0123456789`:

```
$ echo '0123456789 ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩ ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹ ߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉ ०१२३४५६७८९' |
    grep -o '[0-9]\+'
0123456789
٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨
۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸
߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈
०१२३४५६७८
```

That, in general is caused by the pressure to internationalize the characters used. For example: It is perfectly natural for a Greek national to view `αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρσςτυφχψω` as the **lower** case letters. But that is not what has been defined. In fact, all those "character classes" have this limitation added to [its POSIX page definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01):

> In the POSIX locale

That states that the character class is only defined (and valid) in the C locale.
That is most useful to programmers that need stable and well defined lists of characters.
That `[0-9]` could only mean `0123456789` may seem reasonable to programmers.
Equivalently, an `[a-z]` may seem reasonable to only mean `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` to a programmer.
But if `[a-z]` is read as "lower case letters", then, for a Greek national it seems unreasonable to not include any of the `αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρσςτυφχψω` letters. And for an user of the collating order (other than C) it may seem un-reasonable that `[a-z]` doesn't mean `aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYz`. But, in turn, that may be unexpected to a naive user. Many users have complained that the range `[a-z]` was including uppercase letters.

In short: character classes are defined only for the C locale.
The rest of locales have not been defined which prevents their use. There is no way to ask for the lower case letters in Greek. Or to include them in a character range. That is shocking in a present day computer world that easily could use all languages in a web page.

Now, we can improve on that.

Trying to limit the now varied interpretation will most probably be a failure. We need a new syntax. What if we expand character classes to write exactly what we want them to mean:

```
Only digits from ASCII:              [:as:digit:]  <==> 0123456789
Only digits from English:            [:en:digit:]  <==> 0123456789
Only digits from Persian (Farsi):    [:fa:digit:]  <==> ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹
Only lowercase letters from English: [:en:lower:]  <==> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Only lowercase letters from Greek:   [:el:lower:]  <==> αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρσςτυφχψω
Only uppercase from Russian:         [:ru:upper:]  <==> БВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ
.
.
etc.
```

Stable and the same in any/all locale (if the locale could encode the characters).

Who should be contacted to get this idea implemented in some utilities (grep,sed,bash maybe)?

Comment: There's already support via the `\p` syntax in `perl` and `pcre` and even [`javascript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes). Better clean it up and standardize it. The `[:junk:]` is already an eyesore. No need for more ugliness. Eg. this already works to select lowercase greek characters: `echo αβγδабвгabcdABCDАБВГΑΒΓΔ | grep -Po '(?=\p{Greek})\p{Ll}'` => α
β
γ
δ

Comment: http://www.opengroup.org/austin/ (who to contact)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while asking for where to find POSIX specifications is on-topic, questions on where to submit amendment proposals to such specifications is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who should be contacted to get this idea implemented in some utilities (grep,sed,bash maybe)?

There already is some level of support, for example on systems using the GNU C library and its locale definitions, “é” is recognised as lower-case in French locales, and “α” is recognised as lower-case in Greek locales. [Farsi, as defined in the GNU C library, uses ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/locales/fa_IR;h=3714a30932189ab4c29f2db642b6978a3e04cd76;hb=HEAD) in some circumstances (notably, `scanf` and `printf` with the `I` modifier), but they are not part of the “digits” class, and I imagine Sharif FarsiWeb know what they’re doing in this regard.

Suggesting changes of this type is a bit complicated nowadays. You could always join [the Austin Group](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/) and discuss this there, either through [the mailing list](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/lists.html) or [the bug tracker](https://www.austingroupbugs.net) (ideally, start by lurking for a while on the mailing list, or read the archives); but POSIX isn’t really the right place to try to *drive* change without any existing implementations. You could try to suggest the change to the developers of the various tools involved, presumably starting with the locale definitions in some C library or other, but you’re unlikely to get too far without some pressing case (typically, a standards requirement), so you end up in a bit of a Catch-22 situation.

Nowadays I think your best bet is to come up with a valid use-case for an important customer of one of the big operating system editors, and get the change driven that way. Then the editor will take care of all the community-wrangling for you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem's already been addressed in POSIX, using the wide-character functions.  Start with [**`<wctype.h>`**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/wctype.h.html) and [**`<wchar.h>`**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/wchar.h.html), which work with the *current locale*, and [**`<locale.h>`**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) for specifying which locale that might be.

It seems that no one's found it necessary to add special syntax for referencing multiple, unrelated locales in a regular expression.

Comment: Your example comes across as UTF-8, which would be [`el_GR.UTF-8`](https://www.madboa.com/geek/utf8/)

Comment: POSIX provides the mechanism, but (someone may point to a useful source...) doesn't enumerate the possible locales.  So the question is a little ambiguous (no single organization specifies everything) -hth

Comment: neither: I recall that this is the case, but don't have time to dig out a suitable reference to provide for (what is actually) a second question.