# UNIX find command with particular file extension

Tags: linux, find, wildcards

I am trying to find all files in the directories and sub-directories on Desktop with a file name starting with `prac_` followed by two digits and ending in `.c` or `.o`

```
find ./Desktop -type f -name "prac_[0-9][0-9]*" \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.o" \)
```

The problem I'm having is that the above command will bring up files like `prac_99BLAHBLAH.o` when I only want files with the format `prac_99.c`.

Comment: How about `-name 'prac_[0-9][0-9].c' -o -name 'prac_[0-9][0-9].o'`

Answer (score 4):

Using `*` in a filename globbing pattern matches any string whatsoever, so it's correct that the name `prac_99BLAHBLAH.o` matches the pattern `prac_[0-9][0-9]*`, and one of `*.c` or `*.o`.

Instead, use

```
find ./Desktop -type f -name 'prac_[0-9][0-9].[co]'
```

The filename globbing pattern `[co]` matches the single character `c` or `o`, so putting it at the end of the pattern used with `-name` enables you to find filenames that has either character at the end of the name.

Comment: That's the other way round `[[:digit:]]` is `[0123456789]` while `[0-9]` is (or can be) all the characters that sort between 0 and 9 (which can be thousands in some locales on some systems)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Are you sure? GNU `find` finds the file called `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩` when I use `find . -name '*[[:digit:]]*' ! -name '*[0-9]*'` in an UTF-8 locale... I was looking at [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230/116858).

Comment: Is that OpenBSD? That would make it non-compliant. See https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1078. Oh well, I guess outside the POSIX locale `[0123456789]` is the only portable option to only match on those 10 digits.

Comment: See also https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02476.html (where that Q&A you link was mentioned).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the interesting read! Indeed, it's confusing. I'll remove that part of the answer, and will assume that the user knows what they're doing when they use `[0-9]` in whatever locale they're in.

Comment: In that thread, my https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02531.html message is probably the most relevant to this, and would suggest *nobody* (certainly not me) likely knows what they're doing when they use `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're just not restricting the characters between the numbers and file extensions. It can all be a single regex:

```
find ./Desktop -type f -regex ".*/prac_[0-9][0-9][.][co]"
```

- The `.*/` at the beginning is because `-regex` matches on filepaths rather than just filenames.
- The `[.]` is a single-character set that matches a period. It's used because a plain `.` matches any character. Escaping it like `\.` works too, but I tend to avoid that style because the syntax varies across programming languages (e.g., with an extra escape like `\\.` or in a raw string like `r"\."`).

Comment: Is there a particular reason to place the period in `[ ]`?

Comment: @AdminBee The period will match any character unless it is escaped like "\." or is a single-character set like "[.]". I prefer the latter because I jump between a lot of domain-specific config languages and tend to forget when "\." actually needs to be written as "\\." (or r"\." or with backticks, etc).

Comment: I would recommend placing it in the answer, it is among others these little hints that make the site so useful ...