# Find recursively all files whose content match a specific regular expression

Tags: find, regular-expression, file-search

I like to search all PHP files and find a particular string that is identified by a regular expression.

The regular expressions that I use to find the string is:

```
\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s\=\s.{30,50}\;\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s\=\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\(\)
```

I tried to use:

```
grep -r "\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s\=\s.{30,50}\;\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s\=\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\(\)" *.php
```

but this does not seem to work.

```
find . -name '*.php' -regex '\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s\=\s.{30,50}\;\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s\=\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\(\)' -print
```

Does not work either.

I need is to search a path and all subdirectories for PHP files that contain a string identified by the regular expression stated above. What is the best way to accomplish this?

For your information this is a string similar to the ones I try to find:

```
<?php
$tqpbiu = '9l416rsvkt7c#*3fob\'2Heid0ypax_8u-mg5n';$wizqxqk = Array();$wizqxqk[] = $tqpbiu[11].$tqpbiu[5].$tqpbiu[21].$tqpbiu[27].$tqpbiu[9].$tqpbiu[21].$tqpbiu[29].$tqpbiu[15].$tqpbiu[31].$tqpbiu[36].$tqpbiu[11].$tqpbiu[9].$tqpbiu[22].$tqpbiu[16].$tqpbiu[36];$wizqxqk[] = ... etc.
```

[image: regexr com screen of the regular expression and what it finds]

As you probably realize, this is a malware code. So this string is similar but different on each file. However the regular expression code does a good job finding all files if it contains a similar content somewhere in the file.

Before, I had downloaded all files to my windows PC and then used EMEditor to search by regular expression. This works fine on the PC, but for this I need to download everything and it would be nice to be able to search direct on Linux command prompt.

Any tip would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to use single quotes in the grep command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `grep` to search using a regular expression, you have to be aware that `grep` by default interprets the search string as [basic regular expression (BRE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards). The syntax you use contains *extended* regular expression (ERE) syntax, so you would need to use the `-E` flag.

Copying the string example you posted into a file `test.php`, the call

```
~$ grep -E '\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s=\s.{30,50}\;\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s=\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\(\)' *.php

$tqpbiu = '9l416rsvkt7c#*3fob\'2Heid0ypax_8u-mg5n';$wizqxqk = Array();$wizqxqk[] = $tqpbiu[11].$tqpbiu[5].$tqpbiu[21].$tqpbiu[27].$tqpbiu[9].$tqpbiu[21].$tqpbiu[29].$tqpbiu[15].$tqpbiu[31].$tqpbiu[36].$tqpbiu[11].$tqpbiu[9].$tqpbiu[22].$tqpbiu[16].$tqpbiu[36];$wizqxqk[] = ... etc.
```

finds the string (output in bold as highlighted by `grep`), so you could use that with the `-r` option (since you seem to be using GNU `grep`) to recursively look for it.

Also, keep in mind that the `-regex` option of `find` does *not* check if the file *content* matches the regular expression, but rather if the file's *name* matches. To do a regex-based search within all `.php` or `.txt` files using `find`, use

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.php' -o -name '*.txt' \) -exec grep -EH '\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s=\s.{30,50}\;\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s=\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\(\)' {} \;
```

where the `-H` option to `grep` will ensure the filename is printed, too. Alternatively, use `grep -El etc.` to *only* print the filenames (which makes for cleaner output if many files match).

**Some general remarks**

As correctly noted by Stéphane Chazelas, and as reference for possible future readers: several elements of your syntax are non-portable extensions to the regular expression syntax, and the behavior of other constructs may vary depending on the environment settings:

- Character classes (not to be confused with *character lists*) are extensions to the standard ERE. The `\s` shorthand notion e.g. is a Perl extension to regular expressions, and is not necesserily portable across programs designed to handle regular expressions.
- The meaning of range specifications in character lists (such as `[a-z]`) can depend on the locale settings, specifically the *collation order*. The "naive" interpretation that `[a-z]` means `abcdefgh....xyz` is only true in the `C` locale; in others it often means `aAbBcCdD ... xXyYz`, so this needs to be used with care (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414226/377345) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745/377345) for further discussions on the subject). If the program you use supports them, character classes may be a "safer", but as stated, not necessarily portable, way to express that kind of specification (the intention behind your use of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` would be fulfilled with the `[[:alnum:]]` POSIX character class, for example).
- You have escaped several characters that actually don't have a special meaning in (most implementations of) regular expressions, e.g. `\=` and`\;`. This may work in many cases (the GNU `awk` man-page e.g. states

  > `\c`  The literal character `c`

  in the section "String constants"), but should in general be avoided since when trying to port the regex to other programs/environments it may get a special meaning there (in `vim`, `\=` *actually is* a [regex quantifier](http://vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy)), or even within the same program in a future version.

Comment: No worries. It's your answer - do re-edit it to reflect what you want to say